# pandas.read_csv returns unreadable text in just one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, encoding

I am using python 3.7.3 [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
I am trying to create a dataframe with pandas.read_csv and I have two problems. On one side, neither the number of columns (1 instead of 55) nor the number of rows (19.181 instead of 2.272) matches the .xlsm file.

On the other side, the header and rows only show values of unreadable text instead of text strings and numbers (integers, floats).

I have tried several enconding options: 'Latin-1', 'utf-8' and 'ISO-8859-1'.
Also, I have used several 'sep' options: '\t', ';'.

None of them seems to solve the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv(r'MyFile.xlsm', 'Sheet1', engine='python', encoding='latin-1')
df
```

The expected output would be a dataframe with 55 columns and 2272 rows filled with readable text and numbers.

Comment: I believe you should use read_excel instead of read_csv

Comment: It would be better if you show how does your xlsm file looks.

Comment: I changed it to pd.read_excel and now it worked perfectly. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you are now allowed to read excel file from read_csv() function. for that you have to apply
pd.read_excel()